# How to filter comments with vue.js?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

In my view i have this :

```
  <select class="sort_by">
       <option selected disabled>SORT BY</option>
       <option value="name" >Name</option>
       <option value="date">Date</option>
  </select>
```

In my controller i have this:

```
   $comments = $article->comments()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

In my vue i have this:

```
 loadComments: function () {
        articleid = this.article_id;
        this.$http.get('/article/'+ articleid +'/allcomments').then(function(response){
            // True
          data = response.data.comments;
          this.$set('all_comments', data);
          this.comments= data;


        }, function(response){
            // False
        });

      },
```

What i want is when user select name or date, to change `orderBy` and then to display it in view without refresh. Any suggestion how can i do that?

EDIT:
In my ready function i have:

```
this.loadComments();
          setInterval(function () {

           this.loadComments();
         }.bind(this), 20000);
```

So i cant sort by in vue.js, or can i?

Comment: Lodash is your friend for these things, and it's included in the default Laravel project just like Vue. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Comment: I dont know is this what i need because in my ready function im loading comments every n seconds, and if i do like this i will get only for the first time filter but in next time when comments are loaded i will get default sort...

Comment: Ok, wait a moment, I will write an answer.

Comment: add v-model attribute to a select like `v-model="filter"` and then filter output by this parameter whenever you need it by passing to a component  via `v-for="comment in comments | filterBy filter"`

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: I would reconsider using `setInterval`. You have a lot more control if you call a `setTimeout` after the request successfully completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Lodash sortBy method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) inside a **computed property** which acts as a filter. Lodash is included by default in the newest Laravel versions.

Your `.vue` file could look like this:

*(NOTE: This is a Vue 2.0 example, if you are using a previous version of Vue some things can differ)*

```
<template>

    <select v-model="sortingBy" class="sort_by">
        <option selected disabled>SORT BY</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="date">Date</option>
    </select>

    <div v-for="comment in sortedComments">
        // Here your HTML for each comment
    <div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return{
                comments: {},
                sortingBy: "name", // Default sorting type
            }
        },

        computed: {
            sortedComments: function () {
                return _.sortBy(this.comments, [this.sortingBy]);
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loadComments();
            setInterval(function () {
                this.loadComments();
            }.bind(this), 20000);
        },

        methods: {
            loadComments: function () {
                this.$http.get('/article/' + this.article_id + '/allcomments').then((response) => {
                    this.comments = response.data;
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: im not using vue 2.0 its 1.0.26